# How to get getBBox in a jQuerySVG project?

Tags: jquery, svg, bounding, jquery-svg

I have a variable defined as :

```
var myVariable = svg.path(g,"A path here");
```

where g is a group (`var g = svg.group();`)

How to get its bounding box via jQuerySVG ?

I tried myVariable.getBBox(), $(myVariable).getBBox(), but this doesn't work...

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use jQuery SVG (I only use plain JS SVG), but my guess is that `myVariable` is not a DOM element, but some jQuery wrapper. Try `myVariable[0].getBBox()`?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(myVariable)[0].getBBox()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bounding box of the group that contains the path:

```
var box = g.getBoundingClientRect();
```